laravel error in middle of migration using mariadb in docker
I'm running Laravel 9.x in Docker.
This is my .env file :
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=afhasjfaksakjsa

This is my docker-compose.yml file :
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: azureubuntu
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: [project_name]
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - .docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - backend

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8083:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: afhasjfaksakjsa
    networks:
      - backend

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: afhasjfaksakjsa
    networks:
      - backend

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

This is my Dockerfile :
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user

I get an error message when migrating a database on docker.
Error message in terminal :
root@a03d820c3d35:/var/www# php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

  Dropping all tables ................................................................................................................. 1,181ms DONE

   INFO  Preparing database.

  Creating migration table .............................................................................................................. 176ms DONE

   INFO  Running migrations.

  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table .................................................................................................. 235ms DONE
  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table ........................................................................................ 107ms DONE
  2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table ................................................................................ 57ms DONE
  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table ............................................................................................ 102ms DONE
  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table ................................................................................. 168ms DONE
  2023_05_24_083425_create_sessions_table ............................................................................................... 436ms FAIL

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: alter table `sessions` add index `sessions_user_id_index`(`user_id`))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
    756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
    761▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    762▕             );
    763▕         }
    764▕     }

      +18 vendor frames
  19  database/migrations/2023_05_24_083425_create_sessions_table.php:16
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("create")

      +36 vendor frames
  56  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Error message in mariadb container :
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: Failing assertion: fsize != os_offset_t(-1)
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: immediately after the mariadbd startup, there may be
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
2024-07-29 10:20:04 InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 240729  3:20:04 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Sorry, we probably made a mistake, and this is a bug.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Your assistance in bug reporting will enable us to fix this for the next release.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
2024-07-29 10:20:04 diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Server version: 10.6.18-MariaDB-ubu2004 source revision: 887bb3f73555ff8a50138a580ca8308b9b5c069c
2024-07-29 10:20:04 key_buffer_size=134217728
2024-07-29 10:20:04 read_buffer_size=131072
2024-07-29 10:20:04 max_used_connections=1
2024-07-29 10:20:04 max_threads=153
2024-07-29 10:20:04 thread_count=1
2024-07-29 10:20:04 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 468009 K  bytes of memory
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Thread pointer: 0x7f70c4002cc8
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
2024-07-29 10:20:04 where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
2024-07-29 10:20:04 terribly wrong...
2024-07-29 10:20:04 stack_bottom = 0x7f70f01a4d18 thread_stack 0x49000
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Printing to addr2line failed
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(my_print_stacktrace+0x32)[0x555bd67ac0a2]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(handle_fatal_signal+0x475)[0x555bd6258455]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14420)[0x7f70f3655420]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7f70f315900b]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b)[0x7f70f3138859]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0x687766)[0x555bd5ebd766]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0x696227)[0x555bd5ecc227]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0x696539)[0x555bd5ecc539]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0x698ddc)[0x555bd5eceddc]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0x699701)[0x555bd5ecf701]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xec421f)[0x555bd66fa21f]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xec5291)[0x555bd66fb291]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xe4509b)[0x555bd667b09b]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xe86bd6)[0x555bd66bcbd6]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xe874ab)[0x555bd66bd4ab]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xdbddb8)[0x555bd65f3db8]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xd4963e)[0x555bd657f63e]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xd5164b)[0x555bd658764b]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xd57445)[0x555bd658d445]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0x87ff7d)[0x555bd60b5f7d]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_Z17mysql_alter_tableP3THDPK25st_mysql_const_lex_stringS3_P14HA_CREATE_INFOP10TABLE_LISTP13Recreate_infoP10Alter_infojP8st_orderbb+0x434d)[0x555bd60c557d]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_ZN19Sql_cmd_alter_table7executeEP3THD+0x3bb)[0x555bd6130c3b]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0xf0e)[0x555bd601348e]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_ZN18Prepared_statement7executeEP6Stringb+0x4aa)[0x555bd6027a2a]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_ZN18Prepared_statement12execute_loopEP6StringbPhS2_+0xa1)[0x555bd6027c51]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0x7f2cd5)[0x555bd6028cd5]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_Z19mysqld_stmt_executeP3THDPcj+0x30)[0x555bd6028eb0]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcjb+0x1cd0)[0x555bd600ff90]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_Z10do_commandP3THDb+0x13e)[0x555bd601170e]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP7CONNECTb+0x3b7)[0x555bd612bc17]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(handle_one_connection+0x5d)[0x555bd612bf6d]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 mariadbd(+0xc7e436)[0x555bd64b4436]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8609)[0x7f70f3649609]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43)[0x7f70f3235353]
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Trying to get some variables.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Query (0x7f70c401bed8): alter table `sessions` add index `sessions_user_id_index`(`user_id`)
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Connection ID (thread ID): 4
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Status: NOT_KILLED
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,rowid_filter=on,condition_pushdown_from_having=on,not_null_range_scan=off,hash_join_cardinality=off,cset_narrowing=off
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mariadbd/ contains
2024-07-29 10:20:04 information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Writing a core file...
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Resource Limits:
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max processes             unlimited            unlimited            processes 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max open files            1048576              1048576              files     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max locked memory         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max pending signals       63357                63357                signals   
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max nice priority         0                    0                    
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Core pattern: core
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Kernel version: Linux version 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (x86_64-msft-linux-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022
2024-07-29 10:20:04 
2024-07-29 10:20:04 Fatal signal 11 while backtracing
2024-07-29 10:20:06 2024-07-29  3:20:06 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-07-29 10:20:06 2024-07-29  3:20:06 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.18-MariaDB-ubu2004 source revision 887bb3f73555ff8a50138a580ca8308b9b5c069c as process 1
2024-07-29 10:20:06 2024-07-29  3:20:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-07-29 10:20:06 2024-07-29  3:20:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-07-29 10:20:06 2024-07-29  3:20:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-07-29 10:20:06 2024-07-29  3:20:06 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=596564,596564
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 29 pages
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.18 started; log sequence number 646384; transaction id 812
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240729  3:20:07
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] DDL_LOG: Crash recovery executed 1 entries
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-07-29 10:20:07 2024-07-29  3:20:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-07-29 10:20:08 2024-07-29  3:20:08 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
2024-07-29 10:20:08 Version: '10.6.18-MariaDB-ubu2004'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution

Here my docker-compose up without -d :
[+] Running 5/5
 ✔ Network vat_converter_backend  Created                                                                                 0.2s
 ✔ Container mariadb              Created                                                                                 0.2s
 ✔ Container nginx                Created                                                                                 0.2s
 ✔ Container app                  Created                                                                                 0.2s
 ✔ Container phpmyadmin           Created                                                                                 0.2s
Attaching to app, mariadb, nginx, phpmyadmin
app         | [12-Aug-2024 04:55:42] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
app         | [12-Aug-2024 04:55:42] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
app         | [12-Aug-2024 04:55:42] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
app         | [12-Aug-2024 04:55:42] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.18+maria~ubu2004 started.
app         | [12-Aug-2024 04:55:42] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
app         | [12-Aug-2024 04:55:42] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx       | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx       | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.27.0
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 13.2.1 20231014 (Alpine 13.2.1_git20231014)
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
nginx       | 2024/08/12 04:55:42 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.18+maria~ubu2004 started.
phpmyadmin  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
phpmyadmin  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
phpmyadmin  | [Mon Aug 12 04:55:43.592549 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1:tid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.61 (Debian) PHP/8.2.21 configured -- resuming normal operations
phpmyadmin  | [Mon Aug 12 04:55:43.593328 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
mariadb     |
mariadb     |
mariadb     | PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
mariadb     | To do so, start the server, then issue the following command:
mariadb     |
mariadb     | '/usr/bin/mariadb-secure-installation'
mariadb     |
mariadb     | which will also give you the option of removing the test
mariadb     | databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
mariadb     | strongly recommended for production servers.
mariadb     |
mariadb     | See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb
mariadb     |
mariadb     | Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira
mariadb     |
mariadb     | The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.
mariadb     |
mariadb     | Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
mariadb     | https://mariadb.org/get-involved/
mariadb     |
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.18-MariaDB-ubu2004 source revision 887bb3f73555ff8a50138a580ca8308b9b5c069c as process 97
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.18 started; log sequence number 42486; transaction id 14
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@0c9be9fe2711' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@0c9be9fe2711' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:51 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
mariadb     | Version: '10.6.18-MariaDB-ubu2004'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Securing system users (equivalent to running mysql_secure_installation)
mariadb     |
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240812  4:55:56
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 42514; transaction id 15
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete
mariadb     |
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
mariadb     |
mariadb     | 2024-08-12 04:55:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB init process done. Ready for start up.
mariadb     |
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.18-MariaDB-ubu2004 source revision 887bb3f73555ff8a50138a580ca8308b9b5c069c as process 1
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:56 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.18 started; log sequence number 42514; transaction id 14
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240812  4:55:57
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mariadb     | 2024-08-12  4:55:57 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
mariadb     | Version: '10.6.18-MariaDB-ubu2004'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution

Here my docker stats :

Does anyone have a clue what am I missing here ?

I think there might be a problem with MariaDB. If you can give another database like MySQL or SQLite a shot, just run the migration and check if it works. If the migrations run correctly, the issue likely lies with MariaDB.

that means bug from MariaDB and I have to create a ticket to them? @DishanSachin

I should try using MySQL as you suggested @DishanSachin and see if this issue will still exists

opening a ticket or not that something you have to decide.

Do 2 things: 1. The port you invented, 8083, did you set that in your .env file of Laravel? After that do another migrate:fresh, 2. Do docker-compose up -d for all containers except for the mariadb. Now do docker-compose up for mariadb, maybe kill it first, remove it, rebuild it, the usual. That way you'll have a fresh build of MariaDB and you can then diagnose the problem for a proper bug report


if I set 8083 in .env laravel, error Connection refused (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'). 2. I set 3306 in .env laravel and do kill, remove, and fresh build MariaDB container, still same error as above @UnderDog. I tried using MySQL, everything work fine @dishan-sachin.


Ok, in your opening post update all the extra information you have. In your .env copy /paste the database host from that in your opening post. Also : you did docker-compose up without -d so there's a nice log, screenshot that

@UnderDog sorry for the late reply. I have updated extra information for .inv and docker-compose up withoud -d above.

In your .env you have: DB_HOST=mariadb but your Docker container service is: db, so in your .env change it to DB_HOST=db and then try again
